# Python 3: Finding string in a list, returns the strings and NONE

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Code:

```
def find(string_list, search):
    new_list = []
    for i in string_list:
        if search in i:
            new_list.append(i)
    print(new_list)

print(find(['she', 'sells', 'sea', 'shells', 'on', 'the', 'sea-shore'], 'he'))
```

Returns:

```
['she', 'shells', 'the']
None
```

Comment: Default return value of a function is `None`. Remove the print call from `print(find(...`

Comment: The list is printed in the function. And the None is the result of the function.

Answer (score 3):

You're not `return`ing anything, so the function returns `None` by default. Also, you can do this in a more Pythonic way:

```
def find(string_list, search):
    return [i for i in string_list if search in i]
```

This is called a *list comprehension*, and you can read more about them [here](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: At least link to an explanation on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) - they aren't obvious for someone completely new to Python.

Comment: @thegrinner You are correct, I added that.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the more efficient version.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution

```
def find(string_list, search):
    new_list = []
    for i in string_list:
        if search in i:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list

print(find(['she', 'sells', 'sea', 'shells', 'on', 'the', 'sea-shore'], 'he'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The simple switch does the trick! :)